# How to show google maps directions from WebApp inside a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-3, xcode6

I'm working to build a IPA from my WebApp, after run my WebApp inside a UIWebView my page that shows a google maps with a router not works more.

The project was  build using swift and IOS 7.1, there are specific way of make this?

My code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIWebViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var mWebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mWebView.delegate = self

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {

            let url = NSURL(string:"http://my_webapp_.test.com")
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
            mWebView.loadRequest(request)

        } else {

            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "you need internet connection to display the content", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError) {
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

        println(request.URL!.absoluteString)

        if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked {
            if let phoneURL = request.URL where (phoneURL.absoluteString!.rangeOfString("tel://") != nil) {
                if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(phoneURL) {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(phoneURL)
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

any suggestions? thanks in advance!

Comment: your webapp works on browser but not in the webview? ummm.. not sure, but sounds like a `Public API access` issue to me...

Comment: You is right, I have not put  "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" in my info.plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only needed to add this information and it worked!

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription 
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in my info.plist
```